# Get sound from matlab and convert with FFT

Tags: matlab, fft, audio

My question is simple but I am new to MATLAB's sound functions so I am unsure what to do. I would like to read the audio (from the microphone) then apply the `fft(X,n)` function to it where the `n` should be 256. I was applied the fft function to [this code](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audiorecorder.html) like `fft(myRecording,256)` but I kept getting zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this function:

```
function audio_recorder = MicFFT(Fs, update_rate)

recObj = audiorecorder(Fs, 16, 2);
get(recObj);

% Record your voice for time specified by update_rate.

while 1 
    recordblocking(recObj, update_rate);
    myRecording = getaudiodata(recObj);
    subplot (2, 1, 1);
    plot (myRecording);
    xlabel('Time')
    ylabel('Amplitude')
    title('Time domain representation of y(t)')

    L = length(myRecording);
    NFFT = 2^nextpow2(L); % Next power of 2 from length of myRecording
    Y = fft(myRecording,NFFT)/L;
    f = Fs/2*linspace(0,1,NFFT/2+1);

    subplot (2, 1, 2); 
    plot(f,2*abs(Y(1:NFFT/2+1))) 
    drawnow; 
    axis([0 Fs/2 0 0.01])
    title('Single-Sided Amplitude Spectrum of y(t)')
    xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
    ylabel('|Y(f)|')

end

end
```

Fs is the sampling frequency whilst update_rate is the length of each recording

Comment: Nice! recordBlocking() should be recordblocking(). Matlab is getting more picky about case matching

Comment: I understand this example but it is not exactly what I wanted, I probably phrased the question poorly. I wanted to just get the result(vector) of the FFT when applying it against the recording

Comment: @user2958395 Well in this case, the "vector" is in the varialble "Y"